# ie9 not rendering bottom part of background gradient

Tags: css, html, wordpress, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Wordpress and the wp-bootstrap theme from 320press. I have created my own swatch theme for it, and it all works fine, except in IE, where the bottom part of the website, the part that is invisible on page load, is replaced by gray, as if it was never rendered. So the site looks fine until I scroll down.

I've tested this on 3 different IE9 instances.

Has anyone else seen such a rendering error? I can't find anything out on the Internet, and I can't see any errors in the html or the css.

I'd point to the website, but it only exists locally at the moment.

Edit: I found that by deactivating this rule:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d6dae0', endColorstr='#7490a0',GradientType=0 );
```

the problem goes away. Unfortunately it is replaced by

```
background: rgb(214,218,224);
```

which is not a gradient.

I tried to recreate the problem at jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3AFw8/2/ but there it works perfectly.

Comment: Try to recreate the problem at www.jsfiddle.net. It'll help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me I will use .SVG to render for IE9

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

I will recommend you to use : http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: That works. I did use the gradient editor in fact, but I managed to miss the ie9 option. Thanks!